# Proteção contra ataques ddos

Tags: php, ddos

Meu site está sofrendo ataques do tipo DDOS, pelo o que eu li sobre esse tipo de ataque é que não existe uma proteção 100% que possa resolver o problema.

Existe algum método que pelo menos possa retardar ou congelar esses ataques ou algo do tipo para se precaver?

Comment: https://cliente.estadovirtual.com.br/knowledgebase/69/Como-evitar-ataques-DDoS-em-meu-servidor.html já leu esso artigo?  muito bom sobre esse tema

Comment: Defender contra DDoS usando PHP ao meu ver é inútil. A melhor solução é prevenir que as pessoas saibam o IP do ser servidor, se você já sofreu um ataque DDoS eles já sabem, o que é uma tarefa fácil se não utilizar proxy. Utilize algum serviço como Incapsula, CloudFlare (...) eles agem como um proxy, eles serão atacados em seu lugar. Nunca utilize um servidor para mais de um proposito, você tem um "servidor de e-mail" no mesmo servidor? Então isso vai entregar o seu IP. Claro, mude o seu IP após usar o proxy e claro não esteja exposto a outros ataques DoS (ReDOS, HashDoS, SlowHTTP...).